# ImportError: librsvg-2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I am having issues with the rsvg2 library which is a dependency of ffmpeg and opencv.

I have installed ffmpeg using the standard `sudo apt install ffmpeg` and Python-opencv with `pip install opencv-contrib-python`. However trying to run them results in the librsvg2 shared library failing to load:

```
$ ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: librsvg-2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ python -c "import cv2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: librsvg-2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`sudo ldconfig -v` does seem to know about it:

```
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
    librsvg-2.so.2 -> librsvg-2.so.2.44.10
```

However `ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg` indicates that the librsvg-2 is missing.

```
    librsvg-2.so.2 => not found
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to fix this by purging librsvg2 and reinstalling it.

```
sudo apt purge librsvg2-2 librsvg2-dev librsvg2-common
sudo apt install librsvg2-2 librsvg2-dev librsvg2-common
```